# How do I fix service slapd?

Tags: linux, ldap, centos6

I'm installing openldap in my web server. I followed this procedure http://injustfiveminutes.com/category/openldap/. And while I was at it, I couldn't start my slapd service. I always get these errors:

1. "ldif_read_file: checksum error on /etc/openldap/slap.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}monitor.ldif"
2. "ldif_read_file: checksum error on /etc/openldap/slap.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={2}bdb.ldif"

I searched for a solution and found this http://injustfiveminutes.com/2014/10/28/how-to-fix-ldif_read_file-checksum-error/

However, whenever I get to step 6(Compile the check CRC tool). I get these errors:

1. check.c: 324: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 2 of 'crc32' differ in signedness
2. /usr/include/zlib.h:1285: note: expected 'const bytef *' but arguments is of type 'char *'

I'm new to this.
Any steps on how I can fix this? Any help would be great!

Comment: These are not errors, they are warnings. Just continue.

Comment: Oh I see. However "service slapd" is still a fail though. I think I need that to start so that I can get my Active Directory Integration to get going.